# About fs and filesystems tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

A lot of the questions(approx 103) on the [fs](/questions/tagged/fs) (140) seems to be about the `fs` module of Node.js. But there are also some questions(approx 37) that are about [filesystems](/questions/tagged/filesystems) and are being tagged with [fs](/questions/tagged/fs) as the term filesystem is frequently called FS. Is this confusion worth looking into? If yes, maybe we could do one or more of these

1. Decide what `fs` actually means here: filesystem or the node.js module
2. If node.js module then either rename [fs](/questions/tagged/fs) to [node-fs](/questions/tagged/node-fs) (like [node-http-proxy](/questions/tagged/node-http-proxy)) and remove it from other questions(lot of them)
3. Or if it means filesystem, then mark it as synonymous to [filesystems](/questions/tagged/filesystems).

Thoughts?

**Update**

Following the suggestion made by Gilles, I've removed the tag `fs` from the filesystems related questions and tagged them with `filesystems` instead. Now can any moderator rename the tag [fs](/questions/tagged/fs) ro [node.js-fs](/questions/tagged/node.js-fs)?

**Also**, I also seem to have found [file-system](/questions/tagged/file-system). It seems like a synonym to [filesystems](/questions/tagged/filesystems). Thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1):

A two-letter abbreviation is not a good tag name. This tag should be disambiguated. Even if a majority of the uses are about Node.js's `fs`, there's too much potential of misuse from people who aren't familiar with Node.js.

Retag all the [fs](/questions/tagged/fs) questions to use [filesystems](/questions/tagged/filesystems) instead. As usual, if you see anything else that needs to be fixed (other bad tags, spelling, formatting, title, etc.), edit it while you're at it.

Since most of the [fs](/questions/tagged/fs) questions are about Node.js, the best course of action is to go through all of the [non-Node.js `fs` questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fs+-node.js) and retag them appropriately, and when there are none left, get a Stack Overflow moderator to rename the tag.

I would go with [node.js-fs](/questions/tagged/node.js-fs) as the tag name. There are already several `node.js-LIBRARY` tags, and the general format for tag names that are about library is `LANGUAGE-LIBRARY`.

Comment: Oh. Just found out [tag:file-system]. Synonym?

Comment: @Bibhas Many [tag:file-system] questions are really about filesystem access, i.e. [tag:file], rather than filesystems in themselves. But then [tag:filesystems] is also misused this way. So yes, I guess, synonym.

Comment: Done with the retagging. Now where do I ask for renaming the tag? And for the synonym? Updating the question.